# Struggling with slideup()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an accordion menu on the sidebar and this is the code I have.

```
//slide up all the menus that aren't about the current page
if($( "aside li.menu-item-has-children a").parent().hasClass("current-menu-ancestor")) {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
} 

$("aside li.menu-item-has-children a").click(function () {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $(this).next().slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
})
```

The second part, the one about clicking the link works perfectly. The problem is in the first part that should slide up the menus that are not about the current page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening instead - can you please provide more specifics about the problem?

Comment: Add some html (jsfiddle is much better) that shows your problem.